# serializable or serial version in java stream

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream, serialversionuid

Why am i getting this error? Though i have set the serial version but i am not able to do my job .Actually i am trying to read from objectoutputstream . I need data of imageicon from the object outputstream and i am getting error at that line.what am i suppose to do?

The line at which i am getting error is:

1. ImageIcon imageIcon = (ImageIcon) cObjectInputStream.readObject();
2. java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.ImageIcon; local class
       incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID =
       -962022720109015502, local class serialVersionUID = 532615968316031794  at
       java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
           at
       java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
           at
       java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
           at
       java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
           at
       java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
           at
       remoteserver.ClientScreenReciever.run(ClientScreenReciever.java:34)

Comment: Are you creating the stream? The serialVersionUID doesn't match. Try setting the UID in your class to the value in the error message:-962022720109015502

Comment: when i add that in my class it shows an error ,i add this:private static final long serialVersionUID =  532615968316031794;  i also get error when i add  -962022720109015502

Comment: It seems the probem is not with any of your class, but with javax.swing.ImageIcon. DO you use the same Java version on both sides? Shouldn't you send the image file bytes instead of an ImageIcon?

Comment: i figured out that the i was using the different version of java in server and client side. I solve this .But now i am stuck with the problem that i am not able to draw the graphics the server side. i am receiving the image but cannot draw it .